# Saving multiple checkboxlist items in a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want is to be able to check the 4 items I have in my checkboxlist and save them in a cookie. Whenever the user reopens the page the cookies will appear. As I have it now I have it where it will only select 1 of the checkboxes to cookie and if the first one is selected first it goes to it. Very strange and I cannot figure out why all the cookies wont save. So, here is my code for it.

```
foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected && Request.Cookies["CBL"] != null)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies["CBL"].Value;
    }
}
```

and then

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["CBL"].Value = CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue;
    Response.Cookies["CBL"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
}
```

Please someone tell me the error of my ways.

Comment: You need a way to save multiple values to the cookie. Currently you are always replacing what is in the cookie. Try pipedelimiting or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently only storing one value in the cookie. You need to store all the values that are selected and then retrieve all the values. You can try something like below. Pipe delimit the values:

```
//chksOne is checkboxlist in the markup.
//CUSTOM DATASOURCE FOR CHECKBOXLIST REPLACE WITH YOUR DATASOURCE
public List<string> Values = new List<string>() { "CHK 1", "CHK 2", "CHK 3", "CHK 4" };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;

    chksOne.DataSource = Values;
    chksOne.DataBind();

    if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("CBL"))
    {
        string value = Request.Cookies["CBL"].Value;
        if (value == null)
            return;

        string[] vals = value.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0, ii = chksOne.Items.Count; i < ii; i++)
            if (vals.Contains(chksOne.Items[i].Value))
                chksOne.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}

protected void chksOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList list = sender as CheckBoxList;
    if(list == null)
        return;

    List<string> tmpValues = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0, ii = list.Items.Count; i < ii; i++)
    {
        if (list.Items[i].Selected)
            tmpValues.Add(list.Items[i].Value);
    }

    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CBL", string.Join("|", tmpValues.ToArray())));
    Response.Cookies["CBL"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
}
```

To make this re-usable you can create a couple of extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetValues(this CheckBoxList list)
    {
        List<string> tmpValues = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0, ii = list.Items.Count; i < ii; i++)
        {
            if (list.Items[i].Selected)
                tmpValues.Add(list.Items[i].Value);
        }

        return string.Join("|", tmpValues.ToArray());
    }

    public static void SaveValuesToCookie(this CheckBoxList list, string cookieName)
    {
        string values = list.GetValues();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(cookieName, values));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    }

    public static void CheckItemsFromCookie(this CheckBoxList list, string cookieName)
    {
        //MAKE SURE THE COOKIE EXISTS, IF NOT, THERE IS NOTHING WE CAN DO
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(cookieName))
            return;

        //MAKE SURE THE COOKIE HAS VALUE AND IT IS NOT NULL
        string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
        if (value == null)
            return;

        string[] vals = value.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0, ii = list.Items.Count; i < ii; i++)
            if (vals.Contains(list.Items[i].Value))
                list.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Then the how to use code would be:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<string> Values = new List<string>() { "CHK 1", "CHK 2", "CHK 3", "CHK 4" };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
            return;

        chksOne.DataSource = Values;
        chksOne.DataBind();

        //EXTENSION METHOD DEFINED ABOVE
        chksOne.CheckItemsFromCookie("CBL");
    }

    protected void chksOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList list = sender as CheckBoxList;
        if(list == null)
            return;

        //EXTENSION METHOD DECLARED IN CLASS EXTENSIONS ABOVE
        list.SaveValuesToCookie("CBL");
    }
}
```

Comment: chksOne.DataSource = Values; is giving an error. Still works when I delete it except when I change the checkboxes I have to reopen the webpage to see the values in my text box. Working on this solution now..

Comment: Did you declare the List<string> values in your file. I used that just as an example, i dont know what your datasource is for the checkboxlist.

Comment: I thought I had, but I had not. Everything works. There were a few small issues that I had to fix to adjust it to the rest of my code. I see what I wasn't doing correctly and am now rewriting my original code using your's as a reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a model to store selected values.

```
public class CheckedItems 
{
    public bool c1 {get; set;}
    public bool c2 {get; set;}
    ... etc.
}
```

To get/set `any` object from/in cookie you can use these functions:

```
public bool TryGetValueFromCookie<T>(string cookieName, ref T value)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = null;
    if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Any(key => key.Equals(cookieName)))
    {
        cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName);
    }
    if (cookie == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    value = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(cookie.Value);
    return true;
}

public void SetValueToCookie<T>(string name, T value, DateTime expires)
{
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(name) { Value = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(value), Expires = expires };
    Request.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
```